# How can I set a "layout_marginLeft(/Right)" from Constraint Layout Editor?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-layout-editor

I have a app with minSdk=15.

I am trying to migration to ConstraintLayout.

almost ok. but when I change the value of margin_left from **layout editor**, *layout_marginLeft/Right* attrubute is removed.

**before**

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp" 
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" // <- I will set to 16dp from layout editor
    />
```

**after**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                      // <- layout_marginLeft is removed...
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp" // <- it is ok
    />
```

## expected behavior

if I change marginLeft from layout editor,

*layout_marginLeft/Right* and *layout_marginStart/End* is changed.

## update

### I set the value from below

[image]

success change *layout_margineStart/End*, but *layout_marginLeft/Right* is removed.

or

[image]

value is rejected and *layout_marginLeft/Right* is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't how you are changing it, but in my case it is not happening.

Second thing is that why you want to set left and right. you should use start and end.

Still you want to set left and right margin you can do it from attribute tab with click on "view all attribute".

---

You can add it like below

o[image]

click on tool [image](specify design property) button after that you can add it.

like I did it for left margin.

one cache is that it is only for design perspective. it will add tools:layout_margineLeft not android:layout_margineLeft which you needed

Comment: in api level 16, layout_margin_start/end is not supported. so I want to set *layout_marginLeft/Right. And *layout_marginLeft/Right* in "view all attribute" in layout editor, always reject my set value.

Comment: @kyanro ConstraintLayout just came last year, so for api level 16 they are already supporting in layout_margin_start/end If I am not wrong.

Comment: In my api level 16 emulator, it is ignored *android:layout_marginStart/End* attribute. Does it work in real device?

Comment: I need *android:layout_marginLeft/Right*. not *tools:layout_marginLeft/Right*.